# React router 404 issue for sub routes when reloading on server

Tags: reactjs, apache, .htaccess, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using react with react-router to build a website. I have hosted this website on a shared cPanel hosting from Godaddy. It is a linux with Apache server.

The application works fine on natural link routing but when I reload the page on my server it gives a 404 not found. While I understand the problem and made changes in `.htaccess` file to redirect to `index.html` on each request, this works only for top level routes.

Example: This works for `www.mysite.com/about` and `www.mysite.com/users` when reloading. But this does not work for sub routes like `www.mysite.com/users/john` when reloading.

This is my configuration on `.htaccess` file

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

I have no idea about what or how the `.htaccess` file contents does stuff and this is a configuration I took from other Stack Overflow answer. I do not understand how to make changes to this config to support sub routes as well.

Below is the error on console when I reload on sub routes

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at bundle.js:1:1)`

Any help on this is much appreciated!

PS: This works fine on the local webpack dev server with the `historyApiFallback` value set to `true`

Versions:

```
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.4.3",
```

Comment: try to add these code in .htaccess file. RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

Comment: @RamyRagab Doesn't work. Meanwhile, when I reload from these sub routes, I get this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at bundle.js:1:1)`. Not after this change but right from start

Comment: are you have <base href="/" /> in head of index.html if no, add it into head of index.html

Comment: @RamyRagab No. I added it and that worked. Thanks much! If you would add your comment as an answer, I will make that accepted answer. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure that, you have `<base href="/" />` in head of index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React.If the issue persists after adding base href="/" in the head of `public/index.html`, so 1st remove base `href="/"`

You can try 2 solutions from here:

1. Replace "BrowserRouter" with "HashRouter". (just you will find an
   extra "#" gets added in your base route)
2. update or create a 404.html file in the public Directory: e.g.

   ```
   <title>Your Title</title>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     var segmentCount = 1;
     var l = window.location;
     l.replace(l.protocol + '//' + l.hostname + (l.port ? ':' + l.port : '') );
   </script>
   ```